# Use google apps script to extract text from pdf file found at web address and and insert it into a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

In the example below I left the folder and ss blank.

Idea is to retrieve the number after the text "Emerging Markets (" found in the file at the url specified in the code and then insert it into cell b2 in the google sheet specified.

Not getting any errors, but code is not working. Would appreciate your help. Novice here.

Thanks!

```js
const FOLDER_ID = ""; //Folder ID of all PDFs
const SS = "";//The spreadsheet ID
const SHEET = "MSCI";//The sheet tab name


function OpenFile() {
 var url = "https://www.yardeni.com/pub/mscipe.pdf";
  
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  var resource = {
    title: blob.getName(),
    mimeType: blob.getContentType()
  };

  // Enable the Advanced Drive API Service
  var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, {ocr: true, ocrLanguage: "en"});

  // Extract Text from PDF file
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.id);
  var text = doc.getBody().getText();
  
return text;

const identifier = {
    start: `Emerging Markets (`,
    start_include: false,
    end: `)`,
    end_include: false
  };
  let results = getDocItems(docID, identifier);
  return results;
  }

function importToSpreadsheet(results){
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SS).getSheetByName(SHEET);
 
  var cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
  cell.setValue(results);
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger and single step through the script.

Comment: There are no bugs. Code simply does not work.

Comment: Are you sure you want that first return because  that's going to terminate the function.

Comment: Probably not... I said I was a novice. When you say first return, you mean "return text;" ?

Comment: Something's not working and single stepping through the script and checking all intermediate values should find where your going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two functions: `OpenFile()` and `importToSpreadsheet(results)`, but I see no lines where the functions are called.

Just a guess. Perhaps you need to add at the end of your code this line:

```
importToSpreadsheet(OpenFile());
```

**Update**

The `OpenFile()` function gets you all the text. If you need only the part of the text between '**Emerging Markets (**' and '**)**' you can cut it out this way:

```
var text = OpenFile(); // all text
var part = text.split('Emerging Markets (')[1].split(')')[0]; // a part between 'Emerging Markets (' and ')'
importToSpreadsheet(part); // put the part in the cell
```

The lines from `const identifier = {...` to `...return results;` are redundant. Probably they were taken from another sample and don't belong this code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That was interesting, in that it actually wrote something to the sheet - the entire file. I am only interested in in the following - the number after "(Emerging Markets ":

const identifier = {
    start: `Emerging Markets (`,
    start_include: false,
    end: `)`,
    end_include: false
  };
  let results = getDocItems(docID, identifier);
  return results;
  }

Comment: The return value of the function `OpenFile()` is a plain text string. There is no way to get a part of the string as an object property (unless you convert it in an object somehow). So you need to use the plain string methods. Like the `split()`, etc to get some part of the string. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. So should look like this? 
  // Enable the Advanced Drive API Service
  var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, {ocr: true, ocrLanguage: "en"});

  // Extract Text from PDF file
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.id);
  var text = OpenFile(); // all text
  var part = text.split('Emerging Markets (')[1].split(')')[0]; // a part between 'Emerging Markets (' and ')'

}
function importToSpreadsheet(){
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SS).getSheetByName(SHEET);

var cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
cell.setValue(part);
importToSpreadsheet(part);
}

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the code in your comment. It hard to tell if it will work. You can leave all your original code (in your question) intact. Just add those three lines from my updated answer at the end of your code. Your code contains some redundant lines but they don't prevent the code from work.

Comment: Really solid effort thank you! The number was added to the spreadsheet. Only question I have is why multiple copies of the file are saved to google drive.

Comment: Every time you run the script it creates the new file with the same name 'msipe' (Google Drive permits to have files with the same names in one folder). You can remove the file if you put the line `DriveApp.getFileById(file.id).setTrashed(true);` before the line `return text;` -- it will put these files in the trash.

Comment: Yuri thanks again.  I have it looping and looking for more data and it is working perfectly. Well done!